# Making remote request to Google Places API via Express fetches duplicate results everytime

Tags: node.js, express, google-maps-api-3, https, google-places-api

I have been trying to fetch search results via text query using Google places API.

My URL string is

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=${textQuery}&&location=${lat},${lng}&radius=10000&key=${key}
```

GET request from browser works perfectly.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=saravana stores&&location=13.038063,80.159607&radius=10000&key=${key}
```

The above search fetches results relevant to query.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=dlf&&location=13.038063,80.159607&radius=10000&key=${key}
```

This search also fetches results related to dlf.

But, when I tried to do the same via express server, it gives me the same search results for different queries.

```
app.get('/findPlaces', (req, res) => {
  SEARCH_PLACES = SEARCH_PLACES.replace("lat", req.query.lat);
  SEARCH_PLACES = SEARCH_PLACES.replace("lng", req.query.lng);
  SEARCH_PLACES = SEARCH_PLACES.replace("searchQuery", req.query.search);

  https.get(SEARCH_PLACES, (response) => {
    let body = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
        let places = JSON.parse(body);
        const locations = places.results;
        console.log(locations);
        res.json(locations);
    });
  }).on('error', () => {
    console.log('error occured');
  })
});
```

From client side, if I make my first request to `/findPlaces?lat=13.038063&lng=80.159607&search=saravana stores`, I get proper results. When I tried for a different search like `[search=dlf]`, it gives me the same results that I got back from `[search=saravana stores]`. I have even tried to search for different lat, lng with different query search.

However proper results are fetched if I restart my node server. Practically, I cannot restart the server for every new request.

Am I missing something? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are replacing the global variable `SEARCH_PLACES` with the first query. After that, you cannot replace the placeholders again, since they have already been replaced in that string.

Example, when the app starts `SEARCH_PLACES` has this value:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=searchQuery&location=lat,lng&radius=10000
```

After the first request, the global variable will have changed to:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=foo&location=13,37&radius=10000
```

When the second request comes in, there is no longer any placeholder to replace in the string, and thus the last request gets returned again.

---

You want to construct the URL without modifying the global one for every request:

```
const SEARCH_PLACES = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json'

app.get('/findPlaces', (req, res) => {
  const { lat, lng, search } = req.query
  let url = `${SEARCH_PLACES}?query=${search}&location=${lat},${lng}`

  https.get(url, (res) => {
    // ...
  })
})
```